# How to parse the xml when a xml document have multi hierarchy parent ?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse a xml stream from a response to populate some fields in my android app. I can parse the response if the response has one key node item and multiple child within it.

**XML is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<item>
    <id>1</id>    
    <name>Margherita</name>
    <cost>155</cost>
    <description>Single cheese topping</description>
</item> 
<item>
    <id>2</id>    
    <name>Double Cheese Margherita</name>
    <cost>225</cost>
    <description>Loaded with Extra Cheese</description>
</item> 
<item>
    <id>3</id>    
    <name>Fresh Veggie</name>
    <cost>110</cost>
    <description>Oninon and Crisp capsicum</description>
</item> 
<item>
    <id>4</id>    
    <name>Peppy Paneer</name>
    <cost>155</cost>
    <description>Paneer, Crisp capsicum and Red pepper</description>
</item> 
<item>
    <id>5</id>    
    <name>Mexican Green Wave</name>
    <cost>445</cost>
    <description>Onion, Crip capsicum, Tomato with mexican herb</description>
</item> 
</menu>
```

***My xml parser is below***

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

**My Parsing code is**

```
static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME); // name child value
String cost = parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST); // cost child value
String description = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC); // description child value
}
```

**My issue starts when the xml becomes multi level for example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
<item>
<id>1</id>    
<name>Margherita</name>
<originalcost>
<cost>
<ori_cost>$30</ori_cost><tax>$.2</tax>
</cost>
</originalcost>
<description>Single cheese topping</description>
</item> 
</menu>
```

How do I parse the above said example ?

Comment: why don't you use xml pullparser

Answer (score 0):

Quoting docs

> We recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way
>   to parse XML on Android.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

You can use a xml pull parser

```
public class XMLPullParserHandler {

    private String text;

    public XMLPullParserHandler() {

    }



    public Void parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("menu")) {

                    }

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("menu")) {
                        // add employee object to list

                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {

                        Log.i("id is",text);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {

                        Log.i("name is",text);
                    }
                   else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("originalcost")) {


                    }
                   else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("ori_cost")) {

                       Log.i("original cost is",text);
                   }
                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("tax")) {

                       Log.i("tax is",text);
                   }
                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {

                   Log.i("description is",text);
                  }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Log

```
03-18 01:22:39.980: I/id is(954): 1
03-18 01:22:39.980: I/name is(954): Margherita
03-18 01:22:39.990: I/original cost is(954): $30
03-18 01:22:39.990: I/tax is(954): $.2
03-18 01:22:39.990: I/description is(954): Single cheese topping
```

Edit:

To get the xml fom url and convert to input stream

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("url");  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
String  _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity); 
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(_response.getBytes());
```

Edit 2:

```
public class XMLPullParserHandler {

    private String text;

    public XMLPullParserHandler() {

    }



    public Void parse(InputStream is) {
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        XmlPullParser parser = null;
        try {
            factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("xml")) {

                    }

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("xml")) {
                        // add employee object to list

                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("leaders")) {
                         // no value

                    } 
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("leader")) {
                       // no vlaue

                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {

                        Log.i("image is",text);
                    }
                    else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {

                        Log.i("name is",text);
                    }
                   else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("SP DASH")) {


                    }
                   else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("state")) {

                       Log.i("state is",text);
                   }
                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("constituency")) {

                       Log.i("constituency is",text);
                   }
                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("menu")) {

                   Log.i("menu is",text);
                  }
                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {

                      // no vlaue
                     }
                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
                      Log.i("p is",text);

                  }
                  else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("imagelink")) {
                      Log.i("imagelink is",text);

                  }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The log

```
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/image is(1345): hdwallpaperdownloads.com/… 
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/image is(1345):             
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/name is(1345): SP DASH 
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/name is(1345):             
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/state is(1345): Delhi
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/state is(1345):             
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/constituency is(1345): Delhi
03-18 06:38:28.729: I/constituency is(1345):             
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/menu is(1345): profile,gallery,video
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/menu is(1345):             
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/p is(1345): lflsahflkfhalfkhlskfhalh 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/p is(1345):                 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345): hdwallpaperdownloads.com/… 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345):                 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345): hdwallpaperdownloads.com/… 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345):                 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345): hdwallpaperdownloads.com/… 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345):                 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345): hdwallpaperdownloads.com/… 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345):                 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345): hdwallpaperdownloads.com/… 
03-18 06:38:28.739: I/imagelink is(1345):
```

Comment: where do I have to send the URL to get the response?@Raghunandan cause you know I am getting a string as response so can I set the string in setInput instead of the inputstream?

Comment: @Saty you need to dwonlaod the xml from the url and pass it as a inputstream

Comment: okay @Raghunandan
after I download the xml can I write like this.

InputStream in = IOUtils.toInputStream(string, "UTF-8");

Comment: okay @Raghunandan I need a last help from you....how do I know how many numbers of elements are going to get parsed(in my case "item")?

Comment: I did not get the inside node values as you have said and also if there are many items then it only parse one. How would I make this to parse multiple ?

Comment: it will parse all tags. See the log I posted. will work.  tried it before posting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49927/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-saty)